# Animated progress bar - swift

Tags: swift, uikit, progress-bar

I would like to create an animated progress bar. I wrote something like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
    progressView.setProgress(0.1, animated: true)
}
```

I am attaching a link to the video with current progress bar animation
https://files.fm/f/v2spzeaj

Unfortunately, the whole progress view is animated. I would like the animation to apply only to the blue bar. How can I do this?

Edit: 
Code for progress view

```
self.progressView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.161).cgColor 
self.progressView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
self.progressView.layer.shadowRadius = 6
self.progressView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
self.progressView.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5
self.progressView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: show us your code for progressView

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: ok, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. please insert a reproducable example which we can copy and try out ourselves and then we can help you. just a few lines won't  help and this is the reason why nodoy else is answering you....

Comment: This is all my code

Comment: i don't think any compiler of the world can compile this....no import, no func, no nothing!?

Comment: This is all code regarding the progress  view